# Tensorflow returns error when trying to predict a simple two dimensional input

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running following code, trying to create a model to predict [a,b] --> [x,y]

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=2, input_shape=[2])])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
xs = np.array([[-1.0,1],[2,2]], dtype=float)
ys = np.array([[-2.0,2],[5,6]], dtype=float)
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=1000)
res = model.predict([[2,2]])
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 9, in <module>
    res = model.predict([[2,2]])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1096, in predict
    x, check_steps=True, steps_name='steps', steps=steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2382, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 362, in standardize_input_data
    ' but got array with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong here, as the input for the predict() is a perfectly good 2D array.

Comment: Try: `res = model.predict([2,2])`

Comment: Tried and got exact same error:
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: Try: res = model.predict(np.array([[2,2]])). Works on my env.